# Django Error: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. choices are

Tags: python, django

**I am trying to edit data of model UserProfile.
Here is code for same.**

## form.py

```
class UserprofileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['profile_photo', 'gender', 'contact_number', 'age', 'address']
```

## view.py

```
def edit_user(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'service/login.html')
    else:
        userdata = UserProfile.objects.all().filter(user = request.user)
        userd = UserProfile.objects.get(user2 = request.user.pk)
        form = UserprofileForm(request.POST or None, instance = user2)
        if form.is_valid():
            user1 = form.save(commit = False)
            user1.user = request.user
            user1.save()
            return render(request,'service/user.html', {'userdata' : userdata,})
```

Comment: use four spaces to format code

Comment: @Boss : Please accept the edit request that someone has raised for your post. The code format is making things hard to understand.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve keyword 'user2' into field. Choices are:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935129/cannot-resolve-keyword-user2-into-field-choices-are)

Answer (score 4):

The problematic line is
`userdata = UserProfile.objects.all().filter(user = request.user)`
In `filter`, you give the fields in your `User` model which you want to search for. You do not have a `User.user` field in your model and that is why it's giving you an error.

You will also receive an error on `userd = UserProfile.objects.get(user2 = request.user.pk)`, since `user2` is not a field in your `User` model either.

Here is more information regarding the `filter` method:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

The correct way to get the specific user by his unique key (and what I figure the best solution in your scenario) is `UserProfile.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk`